# error building spring webserver from corda samples

Tags: corda

I am trying to run this spring webserver project locally as per https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/spring-webserver using command "gradlew.bat runPartyAServer" and getting the following error "2019-08-14 18:08:20,522 main ERROR Rewrite contains an invalid element or attribute "ErrorCodeRewritePolicy"
", can you please help me fix it? PS: The corda-example nodes are already started and running. (edited)

I have already built the corda examples and they are running but spring webserver is not running but producing error

Comment: Can you share the spring webserver's log output?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error could be the different versions of dependencies.
You can clear the cache and do clean deploy of nodes and run them. 
Once the nodes have started, start runPartyAServer again.

Comment: 1. I opened corda example project in intellij and did clean deployNodes, all the nodes are deployed and running.  

2. Opened spring webserver project in new intellij window and ran "gradlew runPartyAServer" and below is the detailed error.

Comment: You should delete the Gradle cache folder which contains the dependencies files. Path: C:\Users\xxxx\.gradle\caches (where xxxx is the system user). With the next build, Gradle would attempt to download them again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I deleted the cache folder in gradle and clean deploynodes but the errors are still appearing.

Comment: Are you using same versions of dependencies (see below) as used for spring-webserver sample app in Github. 

Link: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/constants.properties

**constants.properties:**

`cordaReleaseGroup=net.corda    
cordaVersion=4.0    
gradlePluginsVersion=4.0.45    
kotlinVersion=1.2.71    
junitVersion=4.12    
quasarVersion=0.7.10    
log4jVersion =2.11.2    
platformVersion=4    
slf4jVersion=1.7.25    
nettyVersion=4.1.22.Final`

Comment: Can you run the webserver again using " --stacktrace" and post the log output as you did earlier?

Comment: 1. Is the distributionUrl for gradle wrapper using same version as given below?

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip`

URL: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

2. Please post all details of the log after performing "--stacktrace".

Is the log displaying below message at the end? 
'"Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings."'

Comment: yes this is what I see in gradle.properties file

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip

this is command 

gradlew --stacktrace --warning-mode all runPartyAServer

I executed in intellij and I get the same output as I posted in the link

Comment: Please confirm if "src/main/resources/application.properties" file is updated 

`1. server.port = defines the HTTP port the webserver listens on    

2. server.port=RPC port the webserver uses to connect to the node    

3. config.rpc.username=RPC user the webserver uses to connect to the node    

4. config.rpc.password=RPC pwd the webserver uses to connect to the node    

5. config.rpc.host=RPC host the webserver uses to connect to the node    

6. config.rpc.port=RPC port the webserver uses to connect to the node`

Comment: yes that seem to match: I am able to reach the end point successfully however I am getting the same error:



node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10004
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10005")
            adminAddress("localhost:10006")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }



spring webserver properties file:

server.port=10055
config.rpc.username=user1
config.rpc.password=test
config.rpc.host=localhost
config.rpc.port=10005

Comment: Similar issue was reported and resolved - See following link - 
[link](https://github.com/corda/samples/issues/18)

Also please report your error in slack at url - 
[link](https://cordaledger.slack.com/)

Comment: thanks, i saw that link earlier. i guess i followed everything mentioned in that stackoverflow but still error occurs. Not sure what else I can do to troubleshoot. Also I have posted this error in slack already..

Answer (score 0):

The exception
"*ERROR Rewrite contains an invalid element or attribute "ErrorCodeRewritePolicy"*" is related to version of log4j2.xml.

Most likely, the ErrorCodeRewritePolicy attribute is not present in the version of log4j2.xml file downloaded by the application.

Following is the structure of code containing ErrorCodeRewritePolicy in a log4j2.xml (see https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/config/dev/log4j2.xml)-

```
<Appenders>.....

 <Rewrite name="Console-ErrorCode-Selector">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Selector"/>
        <ErrorCodeRewritePolicy/>
    </Rewrite>

    <Rewrite name="Console-ErrorCode-Appender-Println">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender-Println"/>
        <ErrorCodeRewritePolicy/>
    </Rewrite>.....
```

Try replacing $log4j_version by "2.7" in the build.gradle. 
Delete the cache and build folders and allow the gradle to download dependencies again.

Replace -

```
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:$log4j_version"
```

By -

```
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.7"
```

Comment: The version that I am currently using is 2.11.2 and that looks more recent

Comment: Didi the error "ErrorCodeRewritePolicy" recur after using version 2.7 of log4j2?

Answer (score 0):

After alot of debugging, tracing in to the internals of Spring, I think there is a bug in the gradle.build file. I commented out these from the dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

    // Corda dependencies.
    compile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    compile "$corda_release_group:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:$spring_boot_version")  // {
  //      exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
  //  }
  //  compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:$log4j_version"
  //  compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:$log4j_version"
    runtime "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect
    compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect', version: '1.3.61'
}
```

Now my code runs without the annoying ErrorCodeRewritePolicy error messages, AND I can configure the log levels from applications.properties.